# ServiceStack 6 /api path causes error for all services

Tags: servicestack

I have an self-hosted application written originally using ServiceStack 3.x, where I had dozens of APIs with a route starting with /api

Upon licensing ServiceStack 6, all routes starting with /api are failing with the following error:

```
"ErrorCode":"NotImplementedException","Message":"The operation 'bu' does not exist for this service"
```

where the last element in the path is shown as the operation name.

I modified one service to route as:

```
[Route("/api/hcm/bu")]
[Route("/api/bu")]
[Route("/access/hcm/bu")]
```

The ones starting with /api fail.  The one starting with /access works perfectly.

These are published APIs, so I really do not want to change them all.

I am guessing the new automatic /api pathways in the newer version of ServiceStack are interfering, but I cannot find any documentation on how to suppress them or work around this.

How can I make the legacy /api path services work again under current ServiceStack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [disable the API Route](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#disable-api-route) with:

```cs
ConfigurePlugin<PredefinedRoutesFeature>(feature => feature.JsonApiRoute = null);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I did search the docs, but the search terms were too common for effective results.   That was what I needed.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ np, link to the feature's docs should be useful for anyone who wants to read about the feature in future.